# problem with searching using specific NSDate in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I am using the following code to search for a specific date entry in Core Data :

```
            //NSDate *tempDate=<a date element fetched from a core data query>

            NSManagedObjectContext *context=[self managedObjectContext];
            RecentMovieInfo *recent3 = nil;
            request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

            entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecentMovies" inManagedObjectContext:context2];
            [request setEntity:entity];

            [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"DateTime=%@",tempDate]];

            recent3 = [[context2 executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
2011-08-03 15:28:59.573 EncameoApp[2447:707] -[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2c4640
2011-08-03 15:28:59.641 EncameoApp[2447:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2c4640'
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set `tempDate`? Are you sure it's an `NSDate` and not an `NSArray`?

The error you're getting says that you're trying to call the selector `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` on a class (in this case an `__NSArrayI`) that doesn't respond to that selector.

Comment: thanks @Nate Thorn ...you just made my day... totally forgot to add "lastObject" ..and was totally dumb not to understand the error message. thanks a bunch !